# Finding Interpolated Data Value

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

This is a question I've had before: I have two arrays representing the inputs and corresponding outputs of a function. I need to find the input for a specific output that falls between data points. How do I do that?

For example:

```
import numpy as np
B = np.arange(0,10,1)
def fun(b):
     return b*3/5

A = fun(B)
```

How to get the value of "B" for `fun` to return 3.75?

Comment: scipy.interpolate.interp1d can be used to generate an interpolation function that can be evalulated at point 3.75, and has options for different types of interpolation such as cubic spline  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

Answer (score 1):

This technique uses linear interpolation to approximate.
I start with this function:

```
def interpABS(A,B,Aval):
    if Aval>max(A) or Aval<min(A):
            print('Error: Extrapolating beyond given data')
    else:        
        if len(A)==len(B):
            for i in np.arange(1,len(A),1):
                ihi = i
                ilo = i-1
                if A[i]>Aval:
                    break
            Alo = A[ilo]
            Blo = B[ilo]
            Ahi = A[ihi]
            Bhi = B[ihi]
            out = Blo + (Bhi-Blo)*(Aval-Alo)/(Ahi-Alo)
            return out
        else:
            print('Error: inputs of different sizes')
```

Note: I'm kind of an amateur and don't know how to set up exceptions, so instead the error outputs are just print commands on a different path from the rest of the function. Those more experienced than I am may recommend improvements.

Use the output array from your function as A, and the corresponding input array as B, then input your target value as Aval. `interpABS` will return the an approximate input for your original function to get the target value

So, for our example above, `interpABS(A,B,3.75)` will return a value of 6.25

This can be useful even if Aval is a value of A to find the corresponding B value, since the math simplifies to `Blo + 0`. For example, changing Aval in the above example will give 5.0, which is part of the original input set B.